# Choosing DB and design for tagging system with 1k+ tags and 1m+ items

Tags: database-design, tagging

I'm creating a system which a user can see a table of items and filter them by tags.
each item can have between 5-30 tags,
a user cannot add new tags,
there is 1,000+ tags,
there is 1,000,000+ items.

What kind of DB should I choose, and how would you advise me to design it.

Comment: Recommendations in SO are considered off-topic, I'm afraid this is not the site for these kind of opinion based questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Standard RDBMS, with three tables: `item`, `tag`, `item_tag`. The last table has a composite PK which is made of the FKs of the two others.

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html